# Insert statement weird error

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am calling a web service in azure and to populate a DB with the following method. I don't know whats wrong..

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      conn.Open();
      string cmdText = String.Format("INSERT INTO UserFiles VALUES('" + obj.userRef.ToString() + "','name','name','name','name','name','name'");
      command.CommandText = cmdText;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
}
```

This is the error msg:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax
>   near 'name'.*
>
> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at _4900ProjectDesktopInterface.Form1.uploadbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Ken\Documents\GitHub\MegaFileUploadConversionService\TestingTool\4900ProjectDesktopInterface\Form1.cs:line
>   152\r\nClientConnectionId:fb95122f-415b-484d-9438-903f0bf2aad0"

Comment: put the table definition and the content of the cmdText in the question please.

Comment: what is the value of `obj.userRef.ToString()`? If it contains a single quote symbol, or some other unescaped symbols, then it may break your query

Comment: At the very least the closing ) for the values is missing from the sql statement.

Comment: You should always use [_parameterized queries_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Your code is open for an [_SQL Injection__](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attakcs.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to list the fields. e.g. INSERT INTO UserFiles (field1, field2) VALUES (..., etc.

Comment: @LeeTaylor not really - as long as the number of values and their type matches the schema.

Comment: obj.userRef.ToString() may have apostrophe (single quote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cmdText` need one more `)` at the end of;

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      conn.Open();
      string cmdText = String.Format("INSERT INTO UserFiles VALUES(@userRef, @name1, @name2, @name3, @name4, @name5, @name6)");
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@userRef", obj.userRef.ToString()); 
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@name1", name); 
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@name2", name); 
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@name3", name); 
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@name4", name); 
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@name5", name); 
      command.Parameters.AddVithValue("@name6", name); 
      command.CommandText = cmdText;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
}
```

As I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586064/insert-statement-weird-error/15586138?noredirect=1#comment22098279_15586064), You should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. Your code is open for an [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attakcs

Comment: You might want to change your answer to use parameters, like you (rightfully) suggest in your comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      conn.Open();
      string cmdText = String.Format("INSERT INTO UserFiles VALUES('" + obj.userRef.ToString() + "','name','name','name','name','name','name')");
      command.CommandText = cmdText;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
}
```

you forget close right parentheses

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are not terminating the open bracket for values? and why are you using **String.Format**? and you can get rid of **conn.close**, since the **using** statement will implicitly do this.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      conn.Open();
      string cmdText = "INSERT INTO UserFiles VALUES('" + obj.userRef.ToString() + "','name','name','name','name','name','name')";
      command.CommandText = cmdText;
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```